# Shopify price variation equation

Tags: jquery, shopify, shopify-template

I am using the Shopify Debut theme and I would like to somehow add vat (7%) to the price of a variation.

Static price I can get working but when changing a variation that has a different price hQuery overwrites this and I don't know how to change this through jQuery.

This is the jQuery snippet from theme.js

```
/**
 * Trigger event when variant price changes.
 *
 * @param  {object} variant - Currently selected variant
 * @return {event} variantPriceChange
 */
_updatePrice: function(variant) {
  if (
    variant.price === this.currentVariant.price &&
    variant.compare_at_price === this.currentVariant.compare_at_price
  ) {
    return;
  }

  this.$container.trigger({
    type: 'variantPriceChange',
    variant: variant
  });
},
```

For single price change in the theme template i use this snippet which works but am not good with jQuery.

```
  {{  compare_at_price | times:1.07 | money }}
```

Full source file of [theme.js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0282/1849/1011/t/1/assets/theme.js?v=17064634885154663115)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in liquid, but in JS, find these lines:

```
  // On sale
  if (variant.compare_at_price > variant.price) {
    $regularPrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(
        variant.compare_at_price,
        theme.moneyFormat
      )
    );
    $salePrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(variant.price, theme.moneyFormat)
    );
    $priceContainer.addClass(this.classes.productOnSale);
  } else {
    // Regular price
    $regularPrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(variant.price, theme.moneyFormat)
    );
  }
```

add replace them with this:

```
// On sale
  if (variant.compare_at_price > variant.price) {
    $regularPrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(
        variant.compare_at_price * 1.07,
        theme.moneyFormat
      )
    );
    $salePrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(variant.price * 1.07, theme.moneyFormat)
    );
    $priceContainer.addClass(this.classes.productOnSale);
  } else {
    // Regular price
    $regularPrice.html(
      theme.Currency.formatMoney(variant.price * 1.07, theme.moneyFormat)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for getting back this worked but it keeps multiplying every time you select an item.
how to change to do only onetime ?

Comment: Try to move that logic closer to the render method e.g. try to move it to `variantPriceChange`. As I don't have access to your source file I can't give you the exact answer.

Comment: Remove everything from the method mentioned in the question, then find this line: "_updatePrice: function(evt) {" and place my code (2 lines from the above) **after** the 1st line of that method, that is starting with `var variant = ...`

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, seems working fine, the price is always the same

Comment: Nice one Vladimir! this seems to have sorted it

Comment: sorry, one last thing! i want to add the original price like in the image above showing '820B - ex-VAT'  but this disappears when u select a variant can this be added to js ?